# Get object properties from symfony form without using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony

ranges is selected from a form. Lets say the user selects 4 & 9. How can I retrieve tests and quizzes in those ranges - and only those ranges, without looping through $ranges? Since $ranges is an object I thought I could use type casting to convert it into a simple array, i.e. (array) $ranges...however that results in an empty array. Ultimately I'm trying to get the id of one range without using a foreach loop

```
$ranges = $form->get('ranges')->getData();

$tests = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Test')->findBy($ranges);
$quizes = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Quiz')->findBy($ranges);

$testsAndQuizzes = array_merge($tests, $quizzes);
```

The purpose of doing this is so once I get to this point, I can loop through my merged array of tests and quizzes and have all the possible outcomes and have one less loop to use.

```
foreach ($testsAndQuizes as $tq) {
    var_dump($tq);//all of $tq's in $ranges 4 & 9.
}
```

Comment: If I understand right you don't know how to do the`findBy($ranges)` part? 
we can't help you on this without knowing what is the relation between `Range` and `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of queries?

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Test');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('test')
    ->where('test.id >= :range_min')
    ->andWhere('test.id <= :range_max')
    ->setParameter(['range_min' => $range_min, 'range_max' => $range_max])
    ->getQuery();

$test = $query->getResult();
```

Do the same for `Quiz`.